# Passing large queries to oozie java action

Tags: oozie

I have an jdbc java class which will run jdbc queries and needs to be triggered from oozie workflow in hdfs.

currently my queries are part of the java code but i need to separate them into a properties file.

I can pass them as parameters, but is there any better way to available sql files directly to the java code in oozie action?

Answer (score 0):

- Dump the queries in text files
- upload the files to HDFS
- in "workflow.xml" reference each HDFS file in a `<file>` element so that Oozie downloads it in the Current Working Dir of the YARN container before starting your Java code
- in "workflow.xml" reference each query file (in order) as `<arg>` of your Java "main()" -- with no path *(remember, they will be present in the CWD)*
- in your Java code, iterate on `args[]` and load/execute each script
- ...
- profit!